# How to mock my_package.__path__?

Tags: python, testing, mocking

I would like to test the following class, and wonder how I could mock `__path__` of a package, so that I could test both scenarios in the `if...else...` control flow.

```
# my_module.py

import my_tools

Class First:
    def __init__(self):
        path = my_tools.__path__[0]
        if path.endswith(".zip"):
            self.a = 1
        else:
            self.a = 2
```

Following is the file structure of my project.

```
.
└── source
    ├── my_tools
    │   └── my_module.py
    └── tests
        └── test_my_module.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `__path__` is a [module attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#__path__), it should be mocked by `PropertyMock` from `unittests.mock`.

```
# content of test_my_module.py
from unittests.mock import patch, PropertyMock
from tools.my_module import First

Class TestFirst:
    @patch("my_tools.my_module.my_tools")
    def test_first(self, mock):
        type(mock).__path__ = PropertyMock(return_value=["/fake/path.zip"]
        my_first = First()
        assert my_first.a == 1
```